# How to find newly added item in the share point site?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

How to find the recently added item in the share point page

If the any user added the items in the custom list, library, list,Announcement, Picture library,etc.........

i need to show all item that added last 2 days. Is that any object model available to find all item in the share point site???Instead of searching every list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right candidate for this is [GetSiteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getsitedata.aspx). You need to get a query to match your requirement and apply the right combination to pull what you want. You have a [Nice Product Whats New](http://smarttools.codeplex.com/) that does same as what you want, you can start with that.